# How to apply Style sheet to label/textfield in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have lots of labels in my application. Is there any way to apply common style sheet to all label rather than giving style to individual label?

Comment: Just make your custom label class by subclassing `UILabel`

Comment: Search for "label" on the site linked, and you'll find several really great UILabel subclasses. http://cocoacontrols.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply 'style sheet' to your native app UI.
You can subclass a UILabel. Style it as you want (although there isn't much you can change other than font, color and background image) and use the custom label objects instead of default UILabel...

Answer (score 2):

you can write a stylesheet class if you use THree20 Library by overriding TTDefaultStyleSheet.

But if your need is minmal,try with custom class with styles written & reference those to UILabel's

Like

constants.h

```
#define COLOR_VALUE  [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5f green:0.5f blue:0.5f alpha:0.5f]
```

then in your file call lblName.textColor = COLOR_VALUE

But not sure you can write all styles using this method!

Answer (score 2):

Create simple UIFont and UIColor categories in your application, and provide semantic descriptions of the data you want to style. Or make “CASCADING STYLE” classes.

This article will explain how: http://akosma.com/2010/06/03/objective-c-categories-as-stylesheets/